# Patch third-party client with custom test resource in pytest

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I've written a client for a third-party service I use in the context of a Django application. I'd like to replace that client during tests so that I can not only patch specific methods on the client but I can also maintain some semblance of state within the test resource to mimic how the real third-party service is in production.

My current setup is this:

```
# app/third_party_client.py

import requests


class TPC:
    def request_new(self, unique_id):
        resp = requests.get('http://foo.bar', data={'blah': unique_id})
        return {'vendor_id': resp.json()['vendor_id'], 'status': resp.json()['status']}

    def request_status_update(self, unique_id, vendor_id):
        resp = requests.get('http://foo.bar', data={'blah': unique_id, 'meh': vendor_id})
        return {'status: resp.json()['status']}
```

```
# app/models.py

from app.third_party_client import TPC

TPC_CLIENT = TPC()


class SomeModel:
    def do_something_with_third_party_service(self):
        response = TPC_CLIENT.request_new(self.unique_id)
        self.vendor_id = response.get('vendor_id')
        self.status = response.get('status')
        self.save()

    def check_status_of_something_with_third_party_service(self):
        response = TPC_CLIENT.request_status_update(self.unique_id, self.vendor_id)
        self.status = response.get('status')
        self.save()
```

```
# tests/resources.py
import random
import string


class TPCResource:
    def __init__(self):
        self.orders = {}

    def request_new(self, unique_id):
        vendor_id = ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, 8))
        self.orders[unique_id] = vendor_id
        return {'vendor_id': vendor_id, 'status': 'pending'}

    def request_status_update(self, unique_id, vendor_id):
        if unique_id not in self.orders.keys() or self.orders[unique_id] == vendor_id:
            raise Exception('This mimics third party')

        return {'status': 'Completed'}
```

I want to figure out how I can replace `TPC` (or its instantiated form in `app/models.py`) with my test resource, `TPCResource` for the duration of tests whose code path calls `some_model. do_something_with_third_party_service()`, etc. I have fixtures, etc set up in pytest, but I'm struggling to figure out how to replace a class or an instance of a class with a custom test resource. Most of the documentation for mocking, patching, and monkeypatching focuses on methods/functions.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine this is a "duh" moment for future viewers, but you can pass in the replacement resource in `mock.patch()`.

In the context of the example above, I did this:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def patched_tpc_client(request):
    tpc_test_resource = TPCResource()
    with mock.patch('app.models.TPC_CLIENT', tpc_test_resource) as tpc_client:
        yield tpc_client
```